# Android Studio xmlns Error Debugging

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, xml-namespaces, android-resources, android-maven-plugin

I'm getting the following error compiling a program using a 3rd party library:

Error:(xx) No resource identifier found for attribute 'tint' in package 'com.example.mycompany.myapp'

The line xx is inside the xml layout that includes a custom component defined in the library.

```
cntrlco:tint="42"
```

The xml namespace documentation says I need the following:

```
xmlns:cntrlco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Here's my best guess as to the problem, but if you think otherwise please let me know, this is a guess.

I suspect I don't have the library installed completely. The reason is that the library instructions want the library installed from maven. I'm not up on this technique, but it appears to be a web based auto install that automates dependency installs while performing the primary install. Nice idea, but I can't install using the web (long story), so I included the .aar file locally.

From my research, installing .aar files locally won't look at its dependencies. If this is true and the "tint" property is defined in a dependency, then this would explain the error I'm seeing.

Is there a way to follow the error chain in more detail so I can verify my theory? Along the way, will this help me find the name of the possible missing dependencies so I can see if including them fixes the problem.